# Что значит "use strict"?

Tags: javascript, javascript-faq

Нередко встречается код со строкой `"use strict";`. Например, библиотеки часто начинаются с этого:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
```

Что значит `"use strict"`, и зачем его использовать?

---

На других языках: [English](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1335851/546661) • [Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/2184/416)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it

Answer (score 224, accepted):

`"use strict";` (перевод: «использовать строгий») - это установка, которая заставляет код обрабатываться в *строгом режиме*. Без этой установки код обрабатывается в *неограниченном режиме*.

Строгий режим был введён в ECMAScript 5, и старые браузеры ([IE9 и младше](http://caniuse.com/#feat=use-strict)) его не поддерживают. То есть, не обращают внимания на установку по умолчанию и всё обрабатывается в неограниченном режиме.

### Зачем использовать `"use strict";`?

В строгом режиме:

- некоторые ошибки можно найти быстрее,
- более опасные и не полезные черты JavaScript либо запрещены, либо приводят к ошибке.

### Как использовать `"use strict";`?

Чтобы включить строгий режим в целом скрипте, надо поставить установку `"use strict";` или `'use strict';` в начало скрипта.

```
"use strict";
// код здесь обрабатывается в строгом режиме
```

Чтобы включить строгий режим в функции, надо поставить установку в начало кода функции.

```
// код здесь обрабатывается в неограниченном режиме
function f() {
  "use strict";
  // код здесь обрабатывается в строгом режиме
}
// код здесь обрабатывается в неограниченном режиме
```

### В чём различие между строгим режимом и неограниченным режимом?

В строгом режиме:

- **нельзя присваивать значение в неопределённую переменную** (спецификация [§11.13.1](http://es5.javascript.ru/x11.html#x11.13.1)). В неограниченном режиме создается глобальная переменная.

  ```
  (function() {
    "use strict";
    x = 5; // ReferenceError: x is not defined
  })(); 

  x = 5; // Создает глобальную переменную x
  ```

  Также нельзя присваивать значение в свойство данных только для чтения.

  ```
  (function() {
    "use strict";
    window.undefined = 5; // TypeError: Cannot assign to read only
  })();                   // property 'undefined' of [object Object]

  window.undefined = 5; // Ничего не делает
  ```
- **нельзя использовать инструкцию `with`** (спецификация [§12.10](http://es5.javascript.ru/x12.html#x12.10)).

  ```
  (function() {
    "use strict";
    with(Object) {} // SyntaxError: Strict mode code may not include a with statement
  })();
  ```
- **в ES5 нельзя определить повторные свойства в литерале объекта** (спецификация [§11.1.5](http://es5.javascript.ru/x11.html#x11.1.5)).

  ```
  (function() {
    "use strict";
    var x = {
      a: 1,
      a: 2
    };  // SyntaxError: Duplicate data property in object literal 
  })(); // not allowed in strict mode

  var x = {
    a: 1,
    a: 2
  }; // x равно {a: 2}
  ```
- **нельзя определить повторные формальные параметры функции** (спецификация [§13.1](http://es5.javascript.ru/x13.html#x13.1), [§15.3.2](http://es5.javascript.ru/x15.3.html#x15.3.2)).

  ```
  function f(a, a) {
    "use strict";
  } // SyntaxError: Strict mode function may not have duplicate parameter names

  function f(a, a) {
    return a;
  }
  f(1,2); // возвращает 2
  ```
- **изменения объекта `arguments` не изменяют аргументы** (спецификация [§10.6](http://es5.javascript.ru/x10.html#x10.6)).

  ```
  function f(x) {
    "use strict";
    arguments[0] = 5;
    return x;
  }
  f(10); // возвращает 10

  function f(x) {
    arguments[0] = 5;
    return x;
  }
  f(10); // возвращает 5
  ```
- **`delete` приводит к ошибке, если аргумент - не изменяемое свойство объекта** (спецификация [§11.4.1](http://es5.javascript.ru/x11.html#x11.4.1)).

  ```
  (function f(x) {
    "use strict";
    var y = 4;
    delete f; // SyntaxError: Delete of an unqualified identifier in strict mode.
    delete x; // SyntaxError: Delete of an unqualified identifier in strict mode.
    delete y; // SyntaxError: Delete of an unqualified identifier in strict mode.
    delete window.undefined; // TypeError: Cannot delete property 
  })();                      // 'undefined' of [object Object]

  (function f(x) {
    var y = 4;
    delete f; // Возвращает false
    delete x; // Возвращает false
    delete y; // Возвращает false
    delete window.undefined; // Возвращает false
  })();
  ```
- **`eval` не может инстанциировать переменные и функции в контексте вызова** (спецификация [§10.4.2](http://es5.javascript.ru/x10.html#x10.4.2)).

  ```
  (function () {
    "use strict";
    eval("var x = 5");
    return x; // ReferenceError: x is not defined
  })();

  (function () {
    eval("var x = 5");
    return x;
  })(); // Возвращает 5
  ```
- **`this` не преобразуется в объект**, а **если значение `this` - `undefined` или `null`, то не преобразуется в глобальный объект** (спецификация [§10.4.3](http://es5.javascript.ru/x10.html#x10.4.3)).

  ```
  function f() {
    "use strict";
    return this;
  };
  f.call(4); // возвращает 4
  f.call(null); // возвращает null
  f.call(undefined); // возвращает undefined

  function f() {
    return this;
  };
  f.call(4); // возвращает [object Number]
  f.call(null); // возвращает [object global]
  f.call(undefined); // возвращает [object global]
  ```
- **`eval` и `arguments` - нельзя изменить или использовать в качестве имени** (спецификация [§11.4.4](http://es5.javascript.ru/x11.html#x11.4.4), [§11.4.5](http://es5.javascript.ru/x11.html#x11.4.5), [§11.13](http://es5.javascript.ru/x11.html#x11.13), [§12.2.1](http://es5.javascript.ru/x12.html#x12.2.1), [§12.10](http://es5.javascript.ru/x12.html#x12.10), [§12.14.1](http://es5.javascript.ru/x12.html#x12.14.1), [§13.1](http://es5.javascript.ru/x13.html#x13.1)).

  ```
  function eval(arguments) {     // SyntaxError: Unexpected eval or arguments in strict mode
    "use strict";
    eval = "5";                  // SyntaxError: Unexpected eval or arguments in strict mode
    ++eval;                      // SyntaxError: Unexpected eval or arguments in strict mode
    arguments++;                 // SyntaxError: Unexpected eval or arguments in strict mode
    try {
      var arguments = 5;         // SyntaxError: Unexpected eval or arguments in strict mode
    } catch(eval) {}             // SyntaxError: Unexpected eval or arguments in strict mode
    return arguments.eval;
  }

  function eval(arguments) {
    eval = "5";
    ++eval;
    arguments++;
    try {
      var arguments = 5;
    } catch(eval) {}
    return arguments.eval;
  }
  eval(); // возвращает 5
  ```
- **нельзя использовать `argument.caller` и `arguments.callee`** (спецификация [§13.2](http://es5.javascript.ru/x13.html#x13.2)).

  ```
  (function f() {
    "use strict";
    arguments.caller; // TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
    arguments.callee; // TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
    f.arguments;      // TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
  })();
  ```
- **больше слов, зарезервированных для использования в будущем** (спецификация [§7.6.1.2](http://es5.javascript.ru/x7.html#x7.6.1.2)).

  ```
  (function () {
    "use strict";
    var implements, let, private, public, yield, interface, package, protected, static;
  })(); // SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
  ```
- **нельзя использовать литералы восьмеричной СС** (спецификация [B.1.1](http://es5.javascript.ru/B.html#B.1.1), [B.1.2](http://es5.javascript.ru/B.html#B.1.2)).

  ```
  (function () {
    "use strict";
    return 010 + // SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.
      "\077";    // SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.
  })();

  (function () {
    return 010 + "\077";
  })(); // возвращает "8?"
  ```

Comment: Круто. Очень хорошо пишете! Какая-то подготовка по technical writing есть или интуитивно так получается?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Формальной подготовки нет, только опыт на английском Stack Overflow. Хотя это не я, это редакторы большое количество моих ошибок исправили (спасибо вам).

Comment: я говорю не о литературном стиле, а об организации информации. Все очень подробно, но структура текста четкая и понятная. Я не знаю JS, но статью легко прочитал.

Comment: @PeterOlson, еще можно добавить, что за счет накладываемых ограничений в strict mode, компилятор/интерпретатор яваскрипта может делать различные оптимизации

Comment: `get eval() { return 5; }` - в этой строке нет ошибки. ES5 разрешает любые ключевые слова в качестве имён полей.

Comment: @Qwertiy Так, вы правы, я исправил ответ.

Comment: Добавлю: компилирующие интерпретаторы javascript в строгом режиме работают быстрее.

Comment: _"нельзя определить повторные свойства в литерале объекта"_ - ES6 **отменяет** это требование. Теперь снова можно.

Comment: _`[object Object]`_ для действий с Window выглядит подозрительно. Мне сейчас хром показывает `#<Window>`, возможно, другие покажут `[object Window]`. Но просто `[object Object]` кажется странным.

Answer (score 3):

Pежим JS Strict появился в ECMAScript 5 стандарте, и устанавливается  строчным литералом `"use strict";` в начале скрипта или функции.

Этим режимом достигается то, что потенциально опасные конструкции языка JS будут запрещены и приведут к исключению.

Сейчас наверное все браузеры поддерживает этот режим, но во время введения, представление ключевых слов строчным литералом гарантировалось то, что новый код продолжал работать и в старых браузерах.
Вещи, которые в строгом режиме приводят к синтаксической ошибке, в старых браузерах, как правило, просто вызывали неправильную работу.

Answer (score -13):

Если в двух словах то 'use strict' этим ты указываешь что используешь ES6 (ECMAScript6), самый последний стандарт JavaScript, который отличается синтаксисом от предыдущего (ES5).

Comment: Нет, вообще нет.

Comment: Объесните пожалуйста, нам учм

Comment: Рядом подробный ответ

Comment: Продолжение...нам учитель показывал пример кода сперва ES5 потом ES6 и вот когда переходил на ES6 просто добавил надпись 'use strict'... значит я все не правильно понял?

Comment: Да, вы правы это совсем не обязательно es6

Comment: ES6 работает и без strict-режима.