# Use strict надо писать или нет?

Tags: javascript

Use strict нужно указывать в начале кода для включения строгого режима так пишет в документации. Строгий режим он нужен только при использовании ECMA Script 5 ? Он идентифицирует что мы пишем ECMA Script 5 ? Объясните пожалуйста я запутался)

Comment: Да, нужно. При ES5+.

Comment: @Vasyok Нет никакой необходимости использовать строгий режим, если вы не знаете, зачем он вам нужен.:) Спокойно пишите свой код без строгого режима.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy Что нет?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, нет, нужно всегда использовать строгий режим.

Comment: @Qwertiy Почему это? И без него хорошо живется.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, потому что без него живётся плохо. Его не для того придумывали, чтобы не использовать.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да я как-то не вижу проблем. Никто не требует, чтобы вы писали в строгом режиме: ни сам стандарт языка, ни браузеры. Это всего лишь ваше личное желание.

Comment: Ну-ну.​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @Qwertiy Только не думайте, что это я поставил минус  вашему ответу. Я лишь обращаю внимание,. что совершенно не требуется указывать строгий режим. Вы можете включать его для одних функций,  а для других функций его не использовать. Никаких проблем с этим не связано. Браузеры обязаны обработать ваш код в соответствии с тем, был ли для отдельной функции установлен строгий режим или нет.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, браузеры обязаны городить костыли вместо оптимизации кода, если строгий режим не используется. Но да, код они выполнят (если сам в нём не накосячишь) - никуда уж не денутся - обратная совместимость же.

Comment: @Qwertiy Браузеры будут работать, как ранее работали. Никаких проблем.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, обрати внимание на ES6 + browser only + nonstrict only в таблицах совместимости. Там реально костыли. Вот тут typeof вернёт undefined, а теперь мы это вызовем и о чудо, оно работает. И куча браузеров failed. И ни одного теста, что должно быть, если блоки переставить.

Comment: @Qwertiy Как код работал, так и будет работать. Я уж не говорю о том, что не все браузеры полностью поддерживают 5-ый стандарт.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, все: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/

Comment: @Qwertiy Вы путаете пожелание с необходимостью. Это две разные вещи. Стандарт ECMA не требует, чтобы был указан строгий режим.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, нужно использовать `'use strict';` для скриптов, написанных в ES5 и новее.

Это указание браузеру, что надо парсить и выполнять скрипт по более современным правилам, а которых сделана попытка исправить некоторые архитектурные косяки js.

Если не ошибаюсь, в сервеных js-средах есть возможность указать его через аргументы командной строки. Можно также написать его на уровне файла. Но для браузеров имеет смысл писать его на уровне самовызывающейся функции-модуля.

Подробнее в вопросе [Что значит "use strict"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435546/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-use-strict)