# "use strict" можно убирать на сайте и использовать только в разработке?

Tags: javascript

"use strict" можно убирать на сайте и использовать только в разработке?

Вопрос не о том что такое "use strict", вопрос о том нужен ли он в готовом скрипте или его достаточно использовать на этапе разработки.

Comment: А... зачем это?

Comment: А кто запрещает?

Comment: Там вроде местами поведение немного поменяться может, так что лучше не надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Директива "use strict" нужна для совместимости со стандартом ES5, так что если вы используете новые фичи из ES5, то для корректной работы скриптов на сайте ее нельзя убирать. Только будьте внимательны - если вам необходимо поддерживать IE8, то эта директива в нем не работает.

Comment: "новые" фичи из ES5)

Comment: ну я имел ввиду по отношению к более раннему стандарту

Comment: это понятно, но все равно вызывает улыбку, в то время как у трети es6 в продакшне, еще треть переходят с разным успехом

Comment: вы уверены, что _Директива "use strict" нужна для совместимости со стандартом ES5_? можете чем-то подкрепить данное утверждение?

Comment: @Grundy объясните по простому: нужна она в готовом проекте или нет?!

Comment: Кстати по идее  "use strict" должен положительно сказываться на производительности, ведь там куча всего не работает.

Comment: @Khipster, а зачем вы ее в не готовом используете? :-) я под вопросом добавил ссылку на объяснение _зачем_ вообще это нужно, почитайте

Comment: @Grundy По моему это сайт троллей каких то честное слово (может тут есть медалька за троллинг?). Неужели сложно просто ответить? Зачем кичиться своими знаниями? Я тоже много чего знаю но я же не выпендриваюсь.

Comment: @Khipster, вы смотрели вопрос по ссылке? [Что значит "use strict"?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435546/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-use-strict) - там все разъяснено: что, зачем и почему.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39757/discussion-between-grundy-and-khipster).