# Выдаёт NaN при компиляции кода задачи чисел Фибоначчи через цикл.В чём проблема?

Tags: javascript, функции, циклы, числа-фибоначчи

```js
"use strict";


function fib(n) {
  var a, b = 1;
  for (var i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
    var c = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = c;
  }
  return b;
}
alert(fib(4));
```

Comment: 1) JS - интерпретируемый язык. 2) `var a = b = 1`

Comment: @MedvedevDev, _var a=b=1;_ - плохой совет, в этом случае `b` утечет в глобальный скоп, а не станет локальной переменной, как задумывалось

Answer (score 3):

Если Вы инициализируете так переменные var a,b = 1; То фактически для наглядности:

```
var a, // a = undefined
    b = 1;
```

Когда Вы делаете `var c = a + b;` Фактически это `c = undefined + 1;` Что будет равно NaN.

Вместо `var a,b=1;` используйте `var a=1, b=1;` Тогда и **a** и **b** будут равно 1;

Comment: _var a=b=1;_ - плохой совет, в этом случае `b` утечет в глобальный скоп, а не станет локальной переменной, как задумывалось

Comment: @Grundy Получается, что b будет объявлена как будто без var?

Comment: да, _b будет объявлена как будто без var_

Comment: @Grundy неожиданный синтаксис. В смысле, неожиданно, то для объявления глобальной переменной её нужно объявить без var.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, так исторически сложилось :-) и с этим борются введением директивы [`use strict`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435547/186999)

Answer (score 0):

`var a, b = 1`

**a** чем-нибудь инициализируйте: `var a = 1, b = 1`

Comment: там a и b равны 1 должны быть, а так да