# Почему возвращается объект?

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста понять что детально происходит при таком вызове:

```js
  String.prototype.camelCase=function(){
     return [typeof this, this];
    }
    
    console.log("camel case word".camelCase());
```

Непонятно в первую очередь почему возвращается тип объект, а не строка.

Я понимаю, что вызов `camelCase()` происходит в контексте "camel case word". То есть `this` будет указывать на эту строку. НО именно на **строку**, а возвращается почему-то, объект.

[image: объект]

Comment: Потому что String это объект и константаная строка приводтся к объекту String автоматом.

Comment: Можно указать `"use strict";` но лучше `return [typeof this, String(this)];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так как данная функция не в [strict моде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435546/186999), `this` внутри нее является **объектом класса String**, а не литералом строки. Поэтому тип соответствующий.

Если добавить директиву `"use strict"`, то будет ожидаемый тобой результат

```js
String.prototype.strictCamelCase = function() {
  "use strict";
  return [typeof this, this];
}

console.log("camel case word".strictCamelCase());
```