# Обязательно ли указывать директиву use strict?

Tags: javascript

Начал изучать Javascript по учебнику http://learn.javascript.ru, где говорится, что по стандарту ES5 нужно указывать директиву 'use strict';, но в интернете попалась сразу же информация, что в ES6 ее указывать уже не требуется.

Так нужно или не нужно указывать сейчас 'use strict';?

Comment: Короткий ответ: да

Comment: @ZhukovRoman Ну и зачем закрывать вопрос дубликатом? Закройте оригинальным вопросом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435546/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82-use-strict

Comment: @AntonShchyrov жаль отката нет ))) На будущее учтём.