# SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode?

Tags: node.js, meteor, puppeteer

Подключаю библиотеку puppeteer, в meteor приложении.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
```

Появляются ошибки в консоли

```
packages/modules.js:22730                     
let asyncawait = true;
^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
```

Версия node js v8.12.0
Версия meteor 1.4.3.2

Из-за чего это может быть и как это поправить?

---

Если вставить строку с кодом

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
```

В файле meteor приложения 
то генерируются такие ошибки:

> packages/modules.js:22730 let asyncawait = true; ^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class)
>   not yet supported outside strict mode
>       at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>       at /home/manking/Р”РѕРєСѓРјРµРЅС‚С‹/it/inetpub/OLAP/svo/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:297:30
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Function.*.each.*.forEach (/home/manking/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.3_2.nlnfuo.2znz++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
>       at /home/manking/Р”РѕРєСѓРјРµРЅС‚С‹/it/inetpub/OLAP/svo/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:128:5
>       at /home/manking/Р”РѕРєСѓРјРµРЅС‚С‹/it/inetpub/OLAP/svo/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:352:5
>       at Function.run (/home/manking/Р”РѕРєСѓРјРµРЅС‚С‹/it/inetpub/OLAP/svo/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
>       at /home/manking/Р”РѕРєСѓРјРµРЅС‚С‹/it/inetpub/OLAP/svo/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:351:11
>   Exited with code: 1 Your application is crashing. Waiting for file
>   change.

Comment: нужно добавить [`"use strict"`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435546/186999)

Comment: Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: а где ты его добавлял? что за приложение? Какие настройки?

Comment: Обычное meteor приложение. 
Если просто в файле js сохраняю и потом запускаю через node. То работает. А если в meteor то такая ошибка.

Comment: чем js файл отличается от meteor?:)

Comment: Добавил текст ошибки в вопрос

Comment: я за тебя поискал в [google](https://www.google.ru/search?q=meteor+Block-scoped+declarations+(let%2C+const%2C+function%2C+class)+not+yet+supported+outside+strict+mode&oq=meteor+Block-scoped+declarations+(let%2C+const%2C+function%2C+class)+not+yet+supported+outside+strict+mode&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.1839j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) и рекомендую просто обновить meteor до последнего релиза. ты, кстати, зачем его используешь?

Comment: Обновлять meteor нельзя.

Comment: тогда вынести генерацию pdf в сервис отдельный от этого проекта и общаться с этим сервисом по простенькому api, э?

Comment: приходиться так делать. Но может как то можно эту проблему решить, чтобы запускать код сразу?

Comment: перейти на wkhtmltopdf

Comment: хотим с него уйти как раз

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84527/discussion-between-norbornen-and-manking).