# Найти общее значения в строках-элементах массива

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется массив:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо получить общее число из всех строк-элементов массив. В данном случае - это число 5.

Comment: Не надо удалять вопрос когда тебе ответили.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = ["3_4_5", "2_5"]
var count = Object.create(null)

for (var a of data) {
  var cur = Object.create(null)
  for (var x of a.split("_")) {
    count[x] = ~~count[x] + ((cur[x] = ~~cur[x] + 1) === 1)
  }
}

var res = Object.keys(count).filter(x => count[x] === data.length)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: А точки с запятой?

Comment: @doox911, и без них работает)

Comment: `use strict` не простил бы таких вольностей)

Comment: @doox911, use strict на них не влияет))

Comment: Как так?) Действительно скушал. Да... Смысла тогда в ней воообще не вижу.

Comment: @doox911, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435547/178988. Или ты про точку с запятой?

Comment: Я про точку с запятой в чтрогом режиме .