# Зачем объявлять переменные в JavaScript через let?

Tags: javascript

Зачем объявлять переменные в JavaScript через `let`, если можно просто написать переменную и сразу присвоить ей значение? Например: зачем писать `let a = 10`, если можно `a = 10`?

Comment: [Тут почитай](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Comment: я джаву скрипт два часа изучаю, я не понимаю

Answer (score 1):

1. в строгом режиме `a = 10` без объявленной `a` даст ошибку

   ```js
   "use strict";

   a = 10;
   ```
2. в не строгом режиме, присваивание без объявления создает **глобальную** переменную, в то время как `let` определяет переменную на уровне блока кода

Comment: что такое строгий режим?

Comment: @Александр [Что значит "use strict"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435547/186999)